# Change headset microphone to internal microphone

Tags: android, microphone, headset

is there a possibility to record audio from the internal phone microphone when a headset is plugged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify [VOICE_COMMUNICATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) as the audio source for your recording. Keep in mind though that this will most likely enable the internal microphone tuned for near-field use-cases (e.g. when you hold the phone next to your ear) rather than far-field use-cases (where you record audio from a few feet away).